# Run group of systemd services and then run a final service

Tags: linux, systemd, services

I want to realize a scenario similar to the following:

Every day at XX:00 an umbrella service is started, e.g. daily_tasks.

When the service starts other services are started that can run in parallel, e.g. backup, cleanup, some_stuff

After all of these have completed there will be another service(s) run, e.g. dismount drives, shutdown.

Now I'm aware of `partOf` and that I can achieve the first two parts: The umbrella service and the *child* services. But I don't know how I can catch that all services are finished and kick off another service or another umbrella service. When I'm creating a simple *empty* umbrella service it has no knowledge of the *child* processes and will continue to run indefinitely.

I'd appreciate any ideas, even if the opinion is that systemd is not designed to handle this!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create a target unit

First create a `.target` unit; this will act as our synchronization point. For this example, let's create `daily-task.target`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run daily tasks
```

### Create daily task services

For services that run in parallel, create `Type=oneshot` service units that (a) are `RequiredBy=daily-task.target` and (b) Run `Before=daily-task.target`.  For example:

#### example1.service

```
[Unit]
Before=daily-task.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'sleep 10; date > /tmp/example1.txt'

[Install]
RequiredBy=daily-task.target
```

#### example2.service

```
[Unit]
Before=daily-task.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'sleep 15; date > /tmp/example2.txt'

[Install]
RequiredBy=daily-task.target
```

### Create post-task services

For services that should run *after* everything is complete, create
service units that (a) are `RequiredBy=daily-task.target`, and that
(b) run `After=daily-task.target`. For example:

example3.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run after all daily tasks are complete
After=daily-task.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'sleep 10; date > /tmp/example3.txt'
ExecStopPost=/sbin/systemctl --no-block --user stop daily-tasks.target

[Install]
RequiredBy=daily-task.target
```

We run `systemctl stop daily-task.target` in this task (via an
`ExecStopPost` hook) in order to move the target into a "stopped"
state; if we don't do this, then next time we try to `systemctl start daily-task.target` nothing will happen, because the target is already
started.

### Enable your services

```
systemctl --user enable example{1,2,3}.service
```

### Start the target

To run our daily tasks, we start the target:

```
systemctl --user start daily-tasks.target
```

If you are watching your logs when this happens, you will see:

```
Sep 06 17:44:19 hostname systemd[5435]: Starting example1.service...
Sep 06 17:44:19 hostname systemd[5435]: Starting example2.service...
Sep 06 17:44:29 hostname systemd[5435]: Finished example1.service.
Sep 06 17:44:34 hostname systemd[5435]: Finished example2.service.
Sep 06 17:44:34 hostname systemd[5435]: Reached target Start daily tasks.
Sep 06 17:44:34 hostname systemd[5435]: Starting example3.service...
Sep 06 17:44:44 hostname systemd[5435]: Stopped target Start daily tasks.
Sep 06 17:44:44 hostname systemd[5435]: Finished example3.service.
```

Due to the dependencies we have created combined with our use of
`Type=oneshot` services, `example1` and `example2` run
*before* `daily-tasks.target` is considered "started", and `example3`
runs once everything else is complete.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

I've read about targets before as umbrella for multiple services, but then I also read on multiple doc pages things like "systemd targets are different states that your system can boot into, comparable to System V runlevels.". That made me think that's not what I should use.

Just one question regarding targets: Can a systemd timer trigger the start of a target?

Comment: Sure. You'll need to explicitly set `Unit=` in your `[Timer]` section.